# No Google or Microsoft account option in System settings

Tags: settings

I just installed elementary os Loki and I can't find an option for Google accounts or Microsoft in the online accounts menu. Is there any way I can install them?
Thanks, Ben

Comment: Is there a way to use Gnome Online Accounts (as a temporary workaround) instead? or is there a beta version of the Google Online Account plugin for eOS? I've been using Evolution for email and it looks great under Loki (though I wish it had the icons of Pantheon Mail and a few additional tweaks...). Evolution will not sync with Google Contacts as it needs Auth02, which is what Gnome Online Accounts provides for Google accounts (+Google Drive support). Even Gnome Contacts won't work as a standalone app without it (it doesn't even boot on eOS for some reason). Pantheon Mail works great until you

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/7616)

Comment: A year later and there's still no IMAP integration <sigh>. Any news on that? I'd love to be able to have my outlook calendar from uni synced with my computer.

Comment: You can install Gnome Control Center to add your Online Accounts, the process is well explained in the following article: https://www.fosslinux.com/1954/how-to-install-google-drive-on-linux-mint-18-1-18-2.htm It was made for Linux Mint but it also works for Elementary OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These services aren't yet supported in Online Accounts, but they may be added in the future. From the [release announcement](http://blog.elementary.io/post/147637979911/loki-04-stable-release):

> The preliminary version of Online Accounts is finally landing in Loki. At the moment, Fastmail and IMAP email accounts are available with more services under development.

For now, you can log into Mail and Calendar with your Google Account. You can also [add an Outlook.com account using IMAP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-your-Outlook-com-account-to-another-mail-app-73f3b178-0009-41ae-aab1-87b80fa94970).

Alternately, you could add both Gmail and Outlook.com as IMAP accounts in Online Accounts. Google support has [details on using IMAP with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en&visit_id=1-636094795547165797-2303127301&rd=1).

Answer (score 6):

Additional account services are still under development. What's available is already present.

Comment: How close we they to being added?

Comment: This is very sad news. I cannot use the mail and calendar because they are considered non-secure apps and then my company does not allow that kind of app. It would be awesome to get the resources working back as it is on other distributions.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Gnome Control Center and Gnome Online Accounts to add your online accounts. The Gnome Control Center will not be displayed in the Applications Menu and will not cause conflicts.

You first have to install Gnome Control Center:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

Then with the following command install Gnome Online Account:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-online-accounts
```

Then to open Gnome Control Center use the following command:

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center --overview
```

Go to the online accounts tab and configure your accounts, hope that i helped.